# Sharepoint Workbench : This site can provide a secure connection

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, gulp, yeoman, workbench

I've created a webpart.
I'm using a Node.js, with npm, Yeoman and Gulp.
I installed a certificate with gulp trust-dev-cert, and I have this error on my page "This site can provide a secure connection", and the app isn't accessible.

This is my package.json

[image]

My node version is 8.9.1.
I tried to change the NODE_NO_HTTP2=1 environment variable , like this [tutorial](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229327/workbench-page-shows-this-site-can-t-provide-a-secure-connection-on-creating-s)  , but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea to resolve my certificate problem ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it isn't working after `NODE_NO_HTTP2=1` changes.

I would suggest that you uninstall the current Node.js installation and reinstall the Node.js with the previous LTS version.

The previous Node.js version is `v 6.12`.

You can download it and install it on your machine and then run the gulp commands.

Link - [Node.js v6.12.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.12.0/)

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1002), currently only Node v6 is supported in SPFx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works with NODE_NO_HTTP2=1